# ASP.NET Core MVC ViewBag always get zero or NULL from other class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, viewbag

I got this  problem when I receive values from a class that use `ExecuteAsync`.

For example check `tempPrice`, this nullable var continue to change every second fraction and it's never zero. Other va are props and can be true, false or null... I always get null.

The following is the action method of a specified controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
        ViewBag.tempPrice = _Strategy.TempPrice.ToString().Replace(".", ",");
        ViewBag.TradingPair = _Strategy.Symbol;
        ViewBag.StopOrderPrice = _Order.StopPriceSpotOrder.ToString().Replace(".", ",");
        ViewBag.CurrentTradePrice = _Trade.LastPublicTrade.ToString().Replace(".", ",");

        return View();
}
```

These are parts of codes where i get values , just for example...

```
public class OrdersFunctions
{
    public string ClientOrderId { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Side { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Only where I manually set the value during app testing (for example)

```
public string Symbol { get; set; } = "ETHBTC";
```

I can get the correct value.

As you can see in the screenshot, every value is set to zero, or null, but in the class that contain vars, are all valued.

[image]

I supposed it was a problem of services Singleton, Transient, etc... but in any case I set them, I always have this problem (with or without interfaces).

Can someone help me?

EDIT :
As results from the following pic, you can see that all my values, during task operation, are OK. ONLY when i pass the values by contructor in this controller, all values go zero to or null.

[image: Order Props]

The pic show that _trade var has Side value filled in main logic class, but it pass a null value to Controller class

I have used this contructor, but nothing... always zero...

```
        public StrategyController(IOptions<StrategyManager> sm, IOptions<TradeFunctions> trade, IOptions<OrdersFunctions> order )
    {
        _Strategy = sm.Value;
        _Order = order.Value;
        _Trade = trade.Value;
    }
```

Comment: How is your _Strategy getting its values?

Comment: By the constructor, see the pic. I pass the classes StrategyManager, TradeFunction and order Function, i call the private read only above and give associations.

Comment: It looks like you only initiate the class but have u pass the value.

Comment: Exactly, all values are zero or null, but all class vars are valued.  Example : ExectuTask cannot be null, bucause it' running at this point. Also Side (that depends from _trade) cannot be null, because i had a trade before